stream builder ConnectionState.waiting when i click on the same page
i have this homepage
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

/** 
 * Future builder is a staeful widhget that subs to a future that will return its value. 
 * value starts calculates returns and finishes. 
 * it takes the shiunk of code that produces the value and subs to it and i will give you the ability to 
 * return various widgets that needs to be returned to the screen 
 * ties ui with db. 
 * 
 */
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  late final EventsService _eventsService;
  late final Future<DatabaseUser> _user;
  late final Stream<List<DatabaseEvent>> _events;

  int _currentIndex = 1;
  String _title = "Crewmunity";

  @override
  void initState() {
    /** we create a new event service every time 
     * so we will create a singleton 
     * we create a service a service or class which is only one in our entire application. 
     * there shouldnt be other copies. 
     * 
     */
    _eventsService = EventsService();
    _eventsService.open();
    _user = _eventsService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail);
    _events = _eventsService.allEvents;

    super.initState();
  }

  // no need for now
  // @override
  // dispose() {
  //   _eventsService.close();
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    final style = theme.textTheme.displaySmall!.copyWith(
      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
    ); // the textTheme has different fonts
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppbar(title: _title),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _user, //_eventsService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _events,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      /**
                     *  listview box scroll view which is a stateless widget
                     * builder we will pass 2 params
                     * we need for the item count to listen to the snapshot. 
                     */
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final allEvents = snapshot.data as List<DatabaseEvent>;
                        allEvents.sort((a, b) => b.date.compareTo(a.date));
                        return EventListView(
                            events: allEvents,
                            onDeleteEvent: (event) async {
                              await _eventsService.deleteEvent(id: event.id);
                            },
                            onTap: (event) {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                  createUpdateEventRoute,
                                  arguments: event);
                            },
                            isUserPage: false);
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }

                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Text("Waiting for all events");
                    default:
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNanBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}

When I load the app the events are displayed properly. When I navigate to other pages there doesn't seem to be any issue. When I click on the navigation bar, on the page that I already am, it goes to the ConnectionState.waiting case and it does not show the events. What am I doing wrong? This happens to the other pages that i have as well

When I click on the navigation bar, on the page you are on, it should not do any action. so you could validate that if you are on the same page that you are accessing, clicking does nothing. using the currentIndex of BottomNavigationBar or validating the route with ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;

Thank you for your solution! I will post how i fixed it below

I have a CustomNavBar class that has a currentIndex parameter.
class CustomBottomNanBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentIndex;

  const CustomBottomNanBar({required this.currentIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: currentIndex, // Current selected index
      onTap: (index) => _onNavBarTapped(context, index),
      showSelectedLabels: false, // Hides the label for the selected item
      showUnselectedLabels: false, // Hides the label for unselected items
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.group),
          label: 'Joined Events',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          label: 'New Event',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          label: 'Search',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _onNavBarTapped(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (currentIndex == index) {
      return;
    }
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        // Handle any logic for the first tab
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          joinedEventsRoute,
          (route) => false, // Remove all previous routes
        );
      case 1:
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          homeRoute,
          (route) => false, // Remove all previous routes
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(createUpdateEventRoute);
        break;
      case 3:
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(searchRoute, (route) => false);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

To solve my issue I used the if statement before the switch state. This way when the user clicks on the same page, the function will not return something and the page does not rebuild.
